# Order of commits after rebasing a branch into another using git

Tags: git, version-control

I have main branch from which I forked out a dev branch a while ago. I continued my development work in dev branch until now. In the meantime, there are newer commits added to the main branch. Now I want to pick up the changes from main to my dev branch. In particular, I want to rebase my changes in dev branch on top of newer changes in the main branch. These are the steps I took :

```
git checkout main
git checkout dev
git rebase main
```

After I went through conflict resolution steps, it looks like the commit from two branches got mixed. Is it how it is supposed to work? I was under the impression that all newer commits from main branch will be at the bottom and the commits of dev branch will be on top of them. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Yes, assuming you did it correctly, the commits from the branch you rebased (in your case `dev`) should come *after* the commits from `main`.

Comment: Note that there are multiple different orders for one set of commits: the *graph* order, the *committer date* order (the time stamps made on each commit when the commit is made), and the *author date* order (the time stamps recorded in terms of when the author made the commit). Since rebase copies commits, it updates the *committer date* on the new copies. Since the new copies occupy a new graph position, this changes the graph order. Since the new copies retain the *author date* by default, this leaves the author date order unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

If you want to reapply the changes from dev branch to main branch (the commits from main branch will be at the bottom and the commits of dev branch will be on top of them), you need the following 2 steps:

1.git checkout dev

2.git rebase main

The rebase working theory like this:

1.find the common ancestor (E in the graph) of dev and main

2.get the diff by comparing the ancestor E and each commit of dev branch (each commit diff saves in different temporary files)

3.Switch to main branch, applying each diff from step2 on main branch one by one

More details in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

```
          A---B---C dev
         /
D---E---F---G   main

D---E---F---G---A’---B’---C’  main
```

**Note:** when applying diff on main branch, it may has conflicts. You need to modify the conflict files and use git add to add the modified files, and then use **git rebase --continue**, so it will applys the next diff on main branch.

**Kindly reminder:** after you finish rebasing, main branch still point to G (see in the graph) and dev branch point to C’. If you want main branch also point to C’, you can use git checkout main and git merge dev

Answer (score 1):

[As Git Doc say](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)After resolving the conflict manually and updating the index with the desired resolution, you can continue the rebasing process with

git rebase --continue